# Proof that subgroup of circle group has infinite order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $z=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$ be in the subgroup of the circle group where $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}$. As we already know, the circle group has infinite order. It's also intuitive for me that this subgroup also has infinite order since there are infinite rational numbers between $0$ and $2\pi$ and thus there are infinite complex numbers $z=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$. So, is there anything tricky here?

Comment: There also infinitely many $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ which are rational multiples of $\pi$, yet for such a $\theta$, $z$ has finite order. The argument required is a bit more subtle.

Comment: @Jason But those $\theta = k\pi$ aren't rational numbers.

Comment: I know. I'm not saying your conclusion is wrong, but your argument is faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many rationals in $[0,2\pi]$, so infinitely many points $e^{i\theta}$ in the sugroup (you have already established that it's a subgroup, apparently).  The points are on the unit circle at angle $\theta $ with the $x$-axis...

Comment: So, basically, nothing tricky...

Comment: @math4everyone Nope.